# Breaking a line in a sorted array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have user input that recieves a string, then adds it into an array and gets displayed on the screen.

As the user inputs more strings, a second list should appear, sorting the list. I'm having trouble getting the second list to break lines between array elements. I think it has something to do with INNERHTML but i'm not completely sure.

```js
  var list =[];

  function buildString()
  {
    // adds items to the list and displays.
    var myVal = document.getElementById('input').value;
    document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML += myVal + "<br>";

}

  function appendArray() {

  //adding input text to array
var input =document.getElementById('input').value;
list.push(input);
document.getElementById("arrayLength").innerHTML = +list.length;
    // displays the length of the array

  }

  function alphaOrder() {
    list.sort();
    document.getElementById('displayAlpha').innerHTML = list + "<br>";
```

```css
    p{
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
      padding:2%;
      font-size:2em;
      color:#aaa;
      text-align:left;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" name="" value="">
    <button type="button" name="button" onclick="buildString(); appendArray(); alphaOrder();">Submit</button>


    <p id="mytext"></p>
    <p id="displayAlpha"> </p>
    <div id="arrayLength"> </div>
```

Comment: this code snippet is not working

Answer (score 2):

You need to join the array of items back into a string with a `<br>` separator.

```
function alphaOrder() {
    list.sort();
    document.getElementById('displayAlpha').innerHTML = list.join("<br>");
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks so much.